# Problem deploying Django site with mod_wsgi

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to set up an apache + mod_wsgi environment for a Django site on Linux Mint. I followed the django site tutorial for this, and mod_wsgi site too. So far I got this:

on my httpd.conf I have this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /site /path/to/wsgi_scripts/django.wsgi

<Directory /path/to/wsgi_scripts>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

in `site.urls` I have this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^site/', include('app.urls')),
)
```

So, if I try to access the url `localhost/site/index`, it shows django view for a non-exists url, but, if I access `localhost/site/site/index`, it works fine.

My question is, which is the way to rid off the first "site" and that the application uses the urls from the alias that I'm using in the httpd.conf. Also, it works if I use the alias in the httpd.conf like this

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi_scripts/django.wsgi
```

but I don't want to use it in this way. Suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "So, if I try to access the url localhost/site/index, it shows django view for a non-exists url, but, if I access localhost/site/site/index, it works fines." sounds like you need to change r'^site/' to r'^site' (remove the trailing slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSGIScriptAlias to /site is effectively making http://localhost/site/ the root for your Django app. Either set your configuration in httpd.conf to be:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi_scripts/django.wsgi
```

or your urls.py in your Django app to be

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'', include('app.urls')), )
```